# ServiceStack OrmLite Multi Self References bug

Tags: c#, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to load references but in this case with two references from the same table it is not working

```
[Required]
public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }

[References(typeof(Employee))]
public int? CreatedById { get; set; }
[Reference]
public Employee CreatedBy { get; set; }

[References(typeof(Employee))]
public int? ModifiedById { get; set; }
[Reference]
public Employee ModifiedBy { get; set; }
```

As you can see above, I did it on the right way as the documentation of ORMLite:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite

It is not loading the properties: ModifieldBy and CreatedBy even if the properties ModifiedById and CreatedById have values. I tried with required fields and it worked, but when I try with int? nulable it doesnt work.

You can see in the picture below that I have one record with the value "5" in the column ModifiedById so my Loadreferences of my method should get the column: ModifiedBy (with the Employee object loaded) it works in other cases, not in this case.
[image]

Comment: I've [added a test that shows multiple self references with nullable ints working](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/388b8c213e4151a47a2057fcd04667e1f3b941e8), can you update to the latest version of ServiceStack if not already, you can also try with the [pre-release version of ServiceStack on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet). If it's still an issue can you post a stand-alone failing test e.g. in a new GitHub repo or in a gist, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a passing test that tests multiple Self References with nullable `int?` Ids [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/388b8c213e4151a47a2057fcd04667e1f3b941e8):

Types Used:

```
public class ParentSelfRef
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(ChildSelfRef))]
    public int? Child1Id { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public ChildSelfRef Child1 { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(ChildSelfRef))]
    public int? Child2Id { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public ChildSelfRef Child2 { get; set; }
}

public class ChildSelfRef
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Drop and re-create tables:

```
db.DropTable<ParentSelfRef>();
db.DropTable<ChildSelfRef>();

db.CreateTable<ChildSelfRef>();
db.CreateTable<ParentSelfRef>();
```

Create record with multiple self references:

```
var row = new ParentSelfRef
{
    Child1 = new ChildSelfRef
    {
        Name = "Child 1"
    },
    Child2 = new ChildSelfRef
    {
        Name = "Child 2"
    },
};
```

Save and test populated row:

```
db.Save(row, references: true);

row.PrintDump();

Assert.That(row.Id, Is.EqualTo(1));
Assert.That(row.Child1Id, Is.EqualTo(1));
Assert.That(row.Child1.Id, Is.EqualTo(1));
Assert.That(row.Child1.Name, Is.EqualTo("Child 1"));
Assert.That(row.Child2Id, Is.EqualTo(2));
Assert.That(row.Child2.Id, Is.EqualTo(2));
Assert.That(row.Child2.Name, Is.EqualTo("Child 2"));
```

Load row with self references:

```
row = db.LoadSingleById<ParentSelfRef>(row.Id);

Assert.That(row.Id, Is.EqualTo(1));
Assert.That(row.Child1Id, Is.EqualTo(1));
Assert.That(row.Child1.Id, Is.EqualTo(1));
Assert.That(row.Child1.Name, Is.EqualTo("Child 1"));
Assert.That(row.Child2Id, Is.EqualTo(2));
Assert.That(row.Child2.Id, Is.EqualTo(2));
Assert.That(row.Child2.Name, Is.EqualTo("Child 2"));
```